# Can't stop MySQL

Tags: mysql, service

When I try to restart MySQL using `restart mysql` I get

```
restart: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; 
  type="method_call", sender=":1.7" (uid=1000 pid=18869 comm="restart mysql ")
  interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Restart" error name="(unset)"
  requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

What's going on? This is Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: tried using sudo or as root user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only ever see messages like this if I forget to use a suitably privileged account. Try

```
sudo restart mysql
```

or obtain a suitably privileged shell and run the command in that.

Comment: Gah, I need more coffee.